# creating pagestyle with one column only for figures

Tags: floats, header-footer, wrapfigure

I have a one-column pagestyle. But some of my pages should have a tighter text column with 1 or 2 figure on the outer side. How can I realize such a design in latex? I tried with wrapfigure and flowframe package. But it did not work out. I would appreciate some help with the coding. Thanks a lot!

Here the preamble definition for the pagestyle:

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\oddsidemargin = 1.4pt
\evensidemargin 1.4pt

\marginparwidth = 0pt
\marginparsep = 0pt
\textwidth = 450.7pt
\headheight = 31.16pt
\headsep = 17pt
\topmargin = -31.16pt
\textheight = 667pt
\footskip = 28.3pt
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for customizing header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{TUM_Outline}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Energy efficiency and climate responsive building design for a sustainable \\ building sector in least-developing countries . Case study: Nepal}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
\markboth{#1}{}}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  It would be helpful if you could add a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with `\end{document}` with some dummy text and images.  Also, I notice that you are defining a lot of lengths for your page layout.  You perhaps would like to have a look at the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package which will greatly simplify your life :)

Comment: Is there any news here?